# Getting cyclic dependency error when adding 'MSAL' service in 'AppInitializationService'

Tags: angular

I am using MSAL service and i am getting the below error when adding msal service in constructor in AppInitializationService.

```
"Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! ApplicationRef ("[ERROR ->]"): in NgModule AppModule in ./AppModule@-1:-1"
```

in App.module.TS i have added the below code :

```
 {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MsalInterceptor,
      multi: true
      },
    AppInitializationService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: appInitializerFn,
      multi: true,
      deps: [AppInitializationService]
    },
```

in AppInitializationService

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AppInitializationService {
  loggedIn = false;
  constructor(private configService: AppConfigService,
    private _tokenService: AppTokenForPrint,
    private _injector: Injector,
    private authService: MsalService,
  ) { }
```

Can you tell me how to solve this?

Comment: @juunas can you help me on this?